# Change title in show event of view for Kendo UI Mobile?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How can I change the title during the show event of a view? This is what I am trying to do but is not doing anything:

```
<div data-role="view" data-show="mobileViewShow">
...
</div>

mobileViewShow: function (e) {
  $.get('services/' + e.params.id))
    .done(function (data) {
      var template = kendo.template('#= id # - #= name #');
      e.options.title = template(data);
    });
};
```

It seems changing the options.title is too late and doesn't display. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Please check the Kendo UI API documentation - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/navbar#methods-title

Comment: I wish the view had this method. Not very intuitive but had to do this `this.header.find('[data-role="navbar"]').data('kendoMobileNavBar').title('my title')`. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: How can I use this approach in an AngularJS Controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
function on_show_view(e)
{
  var id = e.view.params['id'];
  if (id == 0)
    e.view.options.title = "Add Item"
  else  
    e.view.options.title = "Edit Item"
}
```